# If I use Wasm instead of Javascript would this be considered AMP friendly?

Tags: javascript, amp-html, webassembly

I'm new to AMP but from what I understand custom javascript is not recommended when designing AMP pages. I also want to avoid using iframes.

My site will require some custom interactivity so I would like to know if using Wasm would be considered acceptable as regard to AMP validation?

In other words, if my site uses Wasm instead of Javascript would it be considered as a 100% AMP compatible site?

Comment: I've removed the `rust` tag from your question. Even though you may be compiling `rust` to webassembly, the source language itself has no bearing on your question.

Comment: The goal of AMP is not to remove JS, but remove user-scripts of any kind, so caching and loading becomes more efficient. And you can't use WASM anyway, because it needs JS gluecode to work, which won't work in AMP.

Comment: If your site requires custom interactivity maybe it is not an ideal candidate for AMP.

Comment: I’m new to AMP but I’m thinking it might be possible to bootstrap WASM using the new amp-script element?

Answer (score 0):

The [`amp-script`](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/) component allows you to run custom Javascript on your AMP pages while keeping your page valid AMP. This is the recommended way to implement custom interactivity. WASM is currently not supported (and not needed for this use case).

Sidenote: AMP features very powerful primitives such as amp-bind, amp-selector, amp-animation, and amp-form. In many cases, these are enough to implement custom interactivity.